# generate list of files and directories in macOS terminal like find / -ls but adding the columns: creation time date, modified time date

Tags: macos, terminal, find

I need generate list of files and directories in macOS terminal like `find / -ls > list.txt`  but adding the columns: creation time date, modified time date in the begin. Is possible to separate every field with tab char on output?

Comment: You could use something like `find / -exec stat <parameters> {} \;`, but notice that most filesystem don't provide file creation time.

Comment: Almost I got it, but its fail on path with spaces: `find ~/Desktop | while read -r file; do (stat -f %SB;stat -f %Sm $file; stat -f %Sc $file; stat -f %Sp $file; stat -f %Dz $file; stat -f %Su; stat -f %Sg; echo $file;)|tr '\n' '\t';\r; done`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it!

```
echo -e "inode birth\tmodified\tcreated\ttype and permissions\tsize in bytes\tuser id\tgroup id\tmd5 hash\tfile name with full path" | tee "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M") list of files and dirs.txt";find ~ | while read file; do (stat -f %SB "$file";stat -f %Sm "$file"; stat -f %Sc "$file"; stat -f %Sp "$file"; stat -f %Dz "$file"; stat -f %Su "$file"; stat -f %Sg "$file"; md5 -q -s "$file"; echo $file;)|tr '\n' '\t';echo ; done | tee -a "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M") list of files and dirs.txt"
```